# Encryption and decryption from two different tables in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I have looked for a solution and did not find one.

I have a database A with a `Table 1` that has 3 columns with encrypted data.

I also have a database B in which I wish to create views based on the search criteria which will include information from Table 1 and the 3 columns of encrypted data.

I have tried the following to test the encryption and decryption:

On database **A**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[openKey]
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY authKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE authCert
    --SELECT  userSal, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), Decryptbykey(userNameEnc))ownerName FROM Database A.dbo.UserName
END
```

On database **B**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[openUserName]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC Database A.dbo.openKey

    SELECT  
        userSal, 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), Decryptbykey(userNameEnc)) ownerName, 
        userNameEnc 
    FROM 
        DatabaseA.dbo.UserName
END
```

Comment: Yes - nice - and ?!?!? What is your **question**, really??

Comment: My question is that though I tried the above mentioned SP in Database B, it is not giving the Unencrypted name.